# Javascript — Select Elements by Class, Traverse DOM & Assign Class

Tags: javascript

I've been developing websites for a while, but I'm only now starting to tackle JavaScript, mostly because I seem to be terrified by it.

But I've done a few courses, bought a few books, and now I have something I want to write myself. Except it doesn't work and I can't figure it out.

My HTML `img` element has a class of `aligncenter` and is wrapped in a `<p>` tag. I want to get the elements on the rendered page, traverse to the parent `<p>` tag, and assign a class to that tag that will align my image centrally.

So what am I doing wrong here?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

 // select the image
 var image = function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('aligncenter');
 }

 //traverse to parent p tag

 var parent = function() {
  image.elementParentNode;
 }
 // align parent p tag to center

 function assignClass() = {
  parent.classname += "imageCenter";
 }
})
```

Thanks!

Ben

Comment: Why are you using functions? And why are you doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using functions wrong. Moreover, there is no need in functions in your case.

You can simply do:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function()
{      
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("aligncenter");
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
        elems.item(i).parentNode.classList.add('aligncenter');
});
```

However, assigning these values on document load is strange in terms of logic and CSS structure.

Comment: Excellent Yeldar, that worked. But please could you help me understand in what way am I using functions wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @endymion1818 Your functions do not return values. Moreover, functions  should be called this way: `image()`, `parent()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use addClass function of jquery to do this

"element_id".addClass("classname");

Comment: Thanks very much Manoj, however I need to select the elements by class name. Also, I'd like to do this in straight JavaScript so that I understand the underlying language before I take shortcuts. Again, thanks for your contribution.